# Tables for fantasy league and design implementations

Tags: php, mysql

I'm doing a fantasy league site for a card game and was needing in some design implementations suggestions and a few doubts.

A quick context, there will be players, cards and tournaments weekly.

The user will have the option to choose x cards and x players and after each tournament get points according to the chosen cards/players results. Every user can change his players/cards y time before the event starts.

a) the tournaments (results) table seems pretty straight forward for players results, but for cards I would need another table or put all in the same increasing the number of lines and null rows ?

With this I was thinking in this tables:

```
CREATE TABLE results
    (`tournament` varchar(255) , `date` date, `place` varchar(255), `type` varchar(255), `format` varchar(255), `season` int , `player`  varchar(255), `country` varchar(255), `standing` int)
;

INSERT INTO results
    (`tournament`, `date`, `place`, `type`, `format`, `season`, `player`, `country`, `standing`)
VALUES
    ("Poker star","2018-01-15","Berlin","free for all","holdem","1","Michael","US",1)
;



CREATE TABLE user
    (`player` varchar(255), `id` int,   `country` varchar(255), `tournament` varchar(255) , `date` date, `place` varchar(255), `season`  int,`added`)
;

INSERT INTO user
VALUES
   ("Michael",1,"US","Poker star","2018-01-15","Berlin",1,"2017-06-13")
;
```

Now to add card choices should i add row card varchar, quantity and when its used put values otherwise NULL ? Is this a good way to do a database? Add columns with NULL in the not used rows ?

Having so many null columns seems awkward to me.

Now to get the points for a user, I should do a view? Is there a way to trigger and update on a view after x date has passed? (to auto update stats).

Comment: so as a user, I'd select the Ace of Hearts as my card for example?

Comment: @bones yes, and a quantity.

Answer (score 1):

I'd do something like this:

```
player_cards
-------------
id bigint autoincrement
player_id
tournament_id
card_id
card_qty
```

If you don't pick every tournament, you can skip the tournament_id field but it would be impossible to know which cards they had for a particular tournament.